# Layout Attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm probably doing something stupidly wrong. I'm using `Polymer 1.0` and trying to make a very basic module. But when I specify the `Layout Attributes` they won't work. However, if I type `class="layout flex [etc..]"` and so on, it will work. See below:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/time-elements/time-elements.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="x-chat-list">
<template>
    <section class="user-list" layout horizontal>
        <div class="avatar {{color}}" style="background-image: url({{avatar}})">
            <div class="status {{status}}"></div>
        </div>
        <div flex>
            <div class="username">{{username}}</div>
            <div class="text">{{text}}</div>
        </div>
        <time class="timestamp" is="relative-time" datetime="{{timestamp}}"></time>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
        is: 'x-chat-list',
        properties: {
            avatar: '',
            color: '',
            username: '',
            text: '',
            status: '',
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
        }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

It's as if it doesn't recognize Polymer or something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout attributes have been removed in 1.0 and replaced with layout classes ([migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#layout-attributes)). So when you are using the classes, you are doing the right thing.

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks a lot! I read the migration guide but misunderstood it (thought layout classes was only supposed to be used when used outside of dom-module).

Comment: You can also use the custom properties in the stylesheet of your custom elements using @apply.